# In Julia, is there a good way to maintain multiple versions of a package targeted at different releases?

Tags: julia

Right now, there are two relevant versions of Julia: the latest stable 0.3 release, and the 0.4 release under development (which has nightly builds).

Is there currently a good way to have Julia 0.3 and 0.4 versions of the same package, to handle syntax & other changes that occur between Julia versions?

For example, is one of these options possible for packages on METADATA?

- Having Julia 0.3 install one branch and Julia 0.4 install another
- Code flags for Julia 0.3 or 0.4 in the relevant sections

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing to stop you maintaining your package for both Julia versions other than your patience.

For example, you could have `master` of your packages GitHub repository be the Julia 0.4 compatible version, and maintain a separate `julia03` branch for Julia 0.3.

In METADATA, you'd maintain two "series" of releases, e.g. the `0.1.x` series would all point to commits on the `julia03` branch, and the `0.2.x` series would all point to commits on `master`. All these releases would have appropriate lines in their `REQUIRE`/`requires` (`julia 0.3 0.4-` in one and `julia 0.4` in the other).

One other way to think of it is to create a branch in your package everytime you tag a major release. For example, JuMP has a `release06` branch where we can backport small fixes to the `0.6` series of releases, while working on new features on master.

Finally, [Compat.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Compat.jl) has many helpful tools to make code work on Julia 0.3 and Julia 0.4.